# How to avoid spamming a NodeJS function?

Tags: node.js, express

So basicly I have a contact form in my Express application what sends me an email with SMTP. I want to do some checks in the server-side to avoid spamming. What do you advise?

Earlier today somebody just used ~100times in just minutes, probably my mail server banned it after that's why he stopped.

Comment: Look at rate limitation on express

Comment: This? https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit

Comment: Something like that yes

Comment: Well it actually what i need so thank you for mentioning rate limit, did not know such module exists :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit works well. I could set a limit for the contact form's request also another lighter limit for the whole website.

Thanks callmemath in the comments for mentioning rate limitations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use node-schedule package from npm [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule), it will help you to schedule cron jobs whenever you want to send email.

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule')

const job = schedule.scheduleJob('21 * * * *', function(){
  console.log('Send my email.')
})
```

This will excute this cron at exactly 21min of any hour.

You can go through the npm package for more scheduling details.